# How to make RewriteCond change THE_REQUEST but not REQUEST_METHOD

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got this rewrite rule from the internet:

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

The rule works well, but now when I try to send a POST message, this rule will rewrite also the method to GET. This is my form:

```
<form action="check.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
<input type='submit' value='check'>
</form>
```

This is what I got from the server (var_dump($_SERVER))

```
["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
string(3) "GET"
```

I am not really familiar with rewrite rules. Could you tell me how to fix it so that it still process php file extensions but wont touch the REQUEST_METHOD part (from POST to GET)?

Thank you.

UPDATE FULL RULE:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NC] #[R,L,NC]


## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: Use `http://domain.com/check` instead of `check.php`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and still same result. Once I take out the rewrite rule, the post would work as expected.

Comment: I never suggested you to take the rewrite rule out. I suggested you to change your form. From `<form action="check.php" method="post">` to `<form action="http://domain.com/check" method="post">`

Comment: You will still have the issue of the HTTP redirect [**R**]. See my answer below.

Comment: @user1056677 not if he uses the correct address which is the one that is being internally redirected. His rule is only externally redirecting URL's with `.php` not without it as it is internally redirecting when its without `.php` otherwise his pages would not work either.

Comment: @Prix It is an external redirect. Which is why changing the address wont let everything work.

Comment: @user1056677 re-read my comments.

Comment: @Prix The first line is a condition, the second line is the rule for that condition.

Comment: @function1983 do you have any other rules on your .htaccess? because currently the only thing your above mentioned rule does is redirect pages that end with `.php` to a folder like page.

Comment: Please, guys :), thank you for your help so far. 1) I tried to add the full URL, didn't work; 2) I tried to remove the R as suggested, hit 500 error. So now I am reading the rewrite rules guide.. I would take me a while to figure this out by myself so that's why I am asking for your help. Its already 3am here, and I have stuck with this for 4 hours now. :P

Comment: haha, sorry, already did.

Comment: For the external redirect you need the **R**, for the internal you probably want something like RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your `.htaccess` should look like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

You should never use comments on the same lines of the conditions and rules on the `.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NC] #[R,L,NC]
```

As it will break the `.htaccess` from working, comments should be always on a new line.

This is how your form should look like:

```
<form action="http://domain.com/check" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
<input type="submit" value="check">
</form>
```

This should properly return you with the value you want as a POST method.

```
array(1) { ["email"]=> string(4) "text you typed on the input box" }
```

Comment: Can't believe it.. it worked :D. Thank you so much.

And the hash is when I was debugging with the R.

Comment: @function1983 that's OK, glad it worked for you, but keep in mind that on `.htaccess` file if u put the hash in front of the rules, it breaks it.

Comment: I am a java coder. Its my habit from java time. I will be more careful. Thank you for your time again.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a redirect **[R]** - so you are posting to a location which is just dumping the POSTed data and redirecting the request (HTTP GET). The post should be pointed to /dir/foo which could be passed to /dir/foo.php, but you're current .htaccess doesn't allow for that.

Your form should look something like:

```
<form action="/check" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
      <input type='submit' value='check'>
</form>
```

Here's an example of internal routing to .php files.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  # As long as it's not a file
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  # As long as it's not a directory
 RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Prix's solution has fixed it for me.